# PHP - Input string was not in a correct format error

Tags: php, arrays, string, laravel, metaweblog

I'm using laravel and this :

```
https://github.com/comodojo/metaweblog/
```

Here is the code in controller:

```
public function testNewPost() {
    $mwlog = new MetaWeblog("http://example.org/services/metablog.ashx","user","pass");
    $struct = array(
        'title'             =>  "Test Post",
        'description'       =>  "Test Post description",
        'post_type'         =>  "post",
        'categories'        =>  array('uncategorized'),
        'mt_keywords'       =>  array('test','post'),
        'mt_allow_comments' =>  "open",
        'mt_allow_pings'    =>  "open"
    );

    $post = $mwlog->newPost($struct);

}
```

But it returns :

> Input string was not in a correct format.

What's wrong?!

Comment: I'm betting that the categories array expects ID's and not strings. This error typically means a string was searched for an integer, and the string did not contain an integer

Comment: Plugin works with Wordpress. Search problems in your server XmlRpc protocol implementation